# Doesn't save editing text in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I have to `ViewController`s and two classes `MasterViewController.swift` and `LoginViewController.swift`. In first class I have `tableView` in which you can add record and it open new `ViewController` with class `DetailViewController.swift` in with is `textView` in which I can add text and when I go back to `tableView` it must save my text, but when I do it it doesn't save. This is cod from `MasterViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MasterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var isAuthenticated = false

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

    var didReturnFromBackground = false


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
        view.alpha = 0

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "appWillResignActive:", name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object:   nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "appDidBecomeActive:", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func unwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        isAuthenticated = true
        view.alpha = 1.0
    }

    func appWillResignActive(notification : NSNotification) {

        view.alpha = 0
        isAuthenticated = false
        didReturnFromBackground = true
    }

    func appDidBecomeActive(notification : NSNotification) {

        if didReturnFromBackground {
            self.showLoginView()
        }
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(false)
        self.showLoginView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func showLoginView() {

        if !isAuthenticated {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self)
        }
    }

    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
        let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

        newManagedObject.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "date")
        newManagedObject.setValue("New Note", forKey: "noteText")

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            abort()
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)as! NSManagedObject
                (segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController).detailItem = object
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->  Int {
        let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)

            var error: NSError? = nil
            if !context.save(&error) {
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.valueForKey("noteText")!.description
    }


    @IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        isAuthenticated = false
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self)
    }


    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!,        sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {

            abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
     }


    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int,   forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Update:
                self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
            case .Move:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }


}
```

My DetailViewControoler.swift:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    let ManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    @IBOutlet weak var detailTextView: UITextView!

    var note: Note? = nil

    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {

        if let detail: Note = self.detailItem as? Note {
            if let detailTextView = self.detailTextView {
                detailTextView.text = detail.noteText
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.configureView()
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing( textView: UITextView) {

        if let detail: Note = self.detailItem as? Note {
            if let detailTextView = self.detailTextView {
                detail.noteText = detailTextView.text
            }
        }
        ManagedObjectContext.managedObjectContext!.save(nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: If you use a breakpoint, do you see `textViewDidEndEditing` being called?

Comment: Replace `textViewDidEndEditing` with `textViewDidChange:` to ensure that your text is saved. Alternatively implement a button the user can use to explicitly save.

Comment: When I add button it doesn't work. Maybe you know what structure will work for saving data in textView?